# New passport + H1b approval + old passport with h1b visa stamp from previous employment

Tags: usa, h1-visa

My case is like this:

1. I have an H1B visa stamp from employer A in my OLD expired passport. The visa is valid until September 2019.
2. I switched to employer B and applied for H1B again, using my NEW passport. H1B was approved, valid until August 2020.
3. I'm traveling outside the US for a few weeks in May 2018.

Can I avoid going to the consulate again in my home country for visa stamping? Is showing my i797 approval, new passport and visa stamp in the old passport enough to re-enter the US?

Searching the internet tells me it is not necessary to get another stamp for change of employer. But I have a new passport too. So, I'm making sure. Has anyone here been in a similar situation?